# Sluggish refresh when scroll on texteditor

Tags: gedit, cairo-dock, scrolling, geany

it's about two days that I realized that I've got a strange problem on texteditor (gedit, but also Geany and others).

When I scroll the text (with mouse but also with page down/up) it didn't refresh properly.

Only after few clicks on it the situation return to normality.

All other things seems to work nicely (for example: scrolling text on LibreOffice it's not a problem).

It seems a GTK+ problem... but how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE:

It seems that Cairo-dock it's responsable of the problem. With only unity or gnome all works fine, when I launch Cairo dock (OpenGL or not is the same) then gedit and other editors slow on refresh.
Normally I use Cairo dock + Unity session. All worked fine and so I think that the problem starts with the latest update (some days ago).

UPDATE 2:

Trying to install other text editors... for example: X2 editor works fine with the same document that cause problems with gedit/geany.

Comment: Have you tried changing themes? BTW, LibreOffice is also "GTK+". What is your OS? What is your DE?

Comment: +vasa1 Sorry for the lack on information: my DE is cairo dock and my system is Ubuntu 12.04. I try to close cairo... it seems this is the problem!!!! With opengl but also without!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been identified, and is a bug in the Intel drivers of Ubuntu 12.04 :-)

Take a look at the wiki: http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Intel%20cards&lang=en#1-Visual%20artefacts%20when%20scrolling%20in%20some%20windows

Basically, update to the latest version of Mesa, or disable the option "display windows thumbnails" in the Taskbar section.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to Cairo-dock developers it seems is a bug of cairo-dock 3.2.0

I'm not the only one with this kind of problem.

Now they are testing a solution and patch with a 3.2.1 release.

At the moment, I downgrade to 3.1.2, that's work perfectly.

Bye!